# JQUERY Ajax Get Method to get properties of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this assignment of using JQUERY Ajax method in Javascript to get the data of the get request of a Gateway URL and send some of it's property values to the properties of an existing object. I believe there's a simple way to go about it. Below is code and i hope someone out there can help out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Gateway Object</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
              scale=1.0">
  <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script>
    gateway = {
        ip: "",
        hwv: "",

        setIpAddress: function (ip) {
            var self = this;
            self.ip = ip;
        },

        getHardwareVersion: function () {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://" + self.ip + "/command?XC_FNC=GetSI",
                timeout: 2000,
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log("gateway error: check ip address and
                                try again");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        if (data.substr(0, 8) === "{XC_SUC}") {
                            var jString = (data.slice(8));
                            var obj;
                            try {
                                obj = JSON.parse(jString);
                            } catch (e) {
                            }
                            self.hwv = obj.HWV;
                            //console.log(self.hwv);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Error:" + "" + data);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("error with the gateway");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
      };
       gateway.setIpAddress("200.201.51.126");
       gateway.getHardwareVersion();
       console.log(gateway);
   </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

This seems to work fine but "gateway.hwv" can't receive the property of the data object after the ajax request. Is it possible to do this over Ajax-Asynchronous method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using console.log(gateway); directly after gateway.getHardwareVersion(); is not going to work as you're expecting as the log will run before your ajax query has finished processing.

You are going to either need to change your ajax function to by synchronous or run whatever logic you need to run after the ajax call from its success function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `complete` function to the Ajax and call the `console.log` inside it. So it'll show the `gateway` object to you only when the async Ajax request completes.

A sample (I setted the self.hwv to 1 just to fill it):

```
<script>
    gateway = {
            ip: "",
            hwv: "",

            setIpAddress: function (ip) {
                    var self = this;
                    self.ip = ip;
            },

            getHardwareVersion: function () {
                    var self = this;
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "http://" + self.ip + "/command?XC_FNC=GetSI",
                            timeout: 2000,
                            error: function (err) {
                                    console.log("gateway error: check ip address and try again");
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                    if (data) {
                                            if (data.substr(0, 8) === "{XC_SUC}") {
                                                    var jString = (data.slice(8));
                                                    var obj;
                                                    try {
                                                            obj = JSON.parse(jString);
                                                    } catch (e) {
                                                    }
                                                    self.hwv = obj.HWV;
                                                    //console.log(self.hwv);
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                    console.log("Error:" + "" + data);
                                            }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                            console.log("error with the gateway");
                                    }
                            },
                            complete: function() {
                                self.hwv = "1";
                                console.log(gateway);
                            }
                    });
            }
        };
        gateway.setIpAddress("localhost");
        gateway.getHardwareVersion();
 </script>
```